# jQuery scripts not running on Wordpress - I have used hook

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

This one has me tearing my hair out.

I've searched; tried everything I can find.

In functions.php:

```
function masonry_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    if(is_home()){
        wp_enqueue_script('masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('infinite scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/infinite-scroll.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('inf-mas-load', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry-reloader.js', array('jquery', 'masonry', 'infinite scroll'));
    };
};
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'masonry_scripts' );
```

masonry~.js and infinite-scroll.js are local copies of the scripts available on their respective sites.

In masonry-reloader.js:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $container = $('#items');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item-wrap',
            columnWidth: 472,
            gutter: 12
        });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : '#pag.item-wrap',    // selector for the paged navigation 
        nextSelector : '#pag.item-wrap .pagination ul.paglinks li#older',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : '.item-wrap',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
            img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
        },
        // trigger Masonry as a callback
        function( newElements ) {
            // hide new items while they are loading
            var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
            // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                // show elems now they're ready
                $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
            });
        }
        );
});
```

It just doesn't have any affect - like the script isn't running.

Inspect element shows all the scripts load. And masonry~.js is fine, because if I initialise in HTML or no-jQuery-js, it's fine.

I need to use jQuery so that I can append new items from infinite scroll, though.

And it's not because infinite scroll is bad - if I reduce my jQuery to just initialise Masonry (like works fine in HTML), it doesn't initialise. Acts like it isn't even there.

I've been at this for over a week now, I really hope someone can spot my (probably) stupid mistake - I feel like I've tried it all.

Comment: Is there a webpage that you can show us where this is running?

Comment: Um. Okay, it's now live at news.enigma-tech.co.uk.

Comment: So you can see that it's not loading Masonry - but as I say it works perfectly with HTML init of masonry (using `class="js-masonry"`). Also Infinite Scroll isn't working. Both loaded from the same jQuery script, supposedly.

Comment: Oh and this is only on the landing page, btw (you may have noticed the `if(is_home())` condition. Other pages look fairly screwed up at the moment, I just disabled the old/current working theme to make this work-in-progress visible for y'all.

Comment: The line $container.imagesLoaded(function(){ is throwing a js error. Is imagesLoaded a function defined by masonry?

Comment: I didn't write the code, copied and edited. But yeah, it is:http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html - it's throwing an error because infinite scroll isn't loading new images, I imagine.

Comment: The .imagesLoaded function I believe is a function that masonry wants you to implement yourself. Here's someone's implementation: https://gist.github.com/desandro/797120/raw/c75b3447719c817f8f213fef23eb2836f1518acc/gistfile1.js

Comment: Oh, okay. As I say, I copied and pasted the code, tweaked very slightly (for my CSS selectors basically), and included the inf-scroll and masonry source. How should I define this function with the source you link, such that it will pick it up? Same .js file, before the code above?

Comment: Yes, including that before you call it would get rid of the javascript error.

Comment: Changed, Masonry - but not IS - now works on localhost. Neither works on live site.

Comment: On the live site, your #items div is not containing the items. I think you closed out of the div too early.

Comment: That's happened before. I can't explain it, div not closed too early. "fixed" by adding in another div, separate for the Masonry init. Masonry still only initialises if done in HTML. None of my scripts are working.

Comment: Honestly, the more I use Wordpress, the more I appreciate it.. BUT increasingly motivated to learn to build my own CMS.. bugs me so much sometimes with these little things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your script first, then enqueue it:

```
function masonry_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    if(is_home()){
        // Register Scripts
        wp_register_script('masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js');
        wp_register_script('infinite_scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/infinite-scroll.js');
        wp_register_script('inf_mas_load', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry-reloader.js');

        // Enqueue Scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('masonry');
        wp_enqueue_script('infinite_scroll');
        wp_enqueue_script('inf_mas_load');
    };
};
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'masonry_scripts' );
```

Comment: Jquery is registered by WordPress. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe by passing the extra optional params it's registered as well?

Comment: jquery is registered, yes. Your other scripts - not until you register them.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Parameters - my understanding is that since I've passed the $src parameter in enqueue, they don't need to be registered previously.

Comment: Edited anyway, no change.

Answer (score 0):

2 modest suggestions:

1) Provide a dependencies array for masonry and infinite scroll to be sure they load after jQuery.  The order in which you enqueue is not necessarily the order in which the server will send those files.

2) This may seem petty, but that space in the infinite scroll handle `"infinite scroll"` makes me nervous.  WP documentation doesn't seem to forbid spaces, but every one I've ever seen uses dashes or underscores for separation.  Try changing it to `"infinite-scroll"`.

Comment: Thanks, but no impact.